# unable to count words from a text file

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

I'm new to Java and is trying to solve the beginner's problem of counting words in a text file. I have came up with the code below. However, when I tried to run the code, the compile never returns the result. Due to my limited knowledge, I'm really struggling trying to solve this bug. Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
public class WordsCount{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int countingWords = 0;
        try(Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt")))){
            while(sc1.hasNext()){
                sc1.next();
                countingWords++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        System.out.println(countingWords + " words are in the xanadu.txt file");
    }
}



xanadu.txt contents:

In Xanadu did Kubla Khan
A stately pleasure-dome decree:
Where Alph, the sacred river, ran
Through caverns measureless to man
Down to a sunless sea.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
sc1.next();
```

inside of your while loop.

I ran your setup and get 25 words back. When you continually call hasNext() without calling next(), the scanner never moves forward in the buffer. This is the reason the code never breaks out of the while loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice! So awesome to have people like you to help beginners out!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Be sure to mark this as the accepted answer if it solves your issue :)